# Make sure (0,0) is in the line chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

When there is only one point in the line chart I only see the x-axis and y-axis.

But I want to see a line from (0,0) to this point.

I have

```
charts.push(
  dc.lineChart(compositeBrushchart).dimension(dim) 
    .colors(config.charts[x].color)
    .group((add_origin(grp)),config.charts[x].group) 
    .interpolate(config.interpolate) 
    .renderDataPoints(config.renderdatapoints) 
    .renderArea(config.renderarea) 
    .renderDataPoints({radius: config.charts[x].symbolsize})     
    .dashStyle(config.charts[x].dash.split(","))
```

Comment: Please see if [this recent issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1656) is helpful. You need to provide some data in order for dc.js & d3 to know the scale and draw anything, so I think you will need to fake it, as my comment shows.

Comment: You mean you just want to add the text “0” at the corner of the chart when there is no data?

Comment: No from 0 value i need to draw the line, Like when there is a 0 value label is not showing up i want to show that label as well

Comment: I don’t get it, or don’t get how that’s different from the issue I linked earlier. Maybe you could edit your question and add images of the actual and desired behavior.

Comment: Ok , I want draw the line which is always start from (0,0) to the specified point

Comment: Okay, I edited your question to make this more clear, and I'll post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to preprocess your data, to add or remove points that come from the crossfilter group.

Each time a chart draws, it will call `group.all()` to get its data. If you wrap your group in another object, you can modify the data.

In your case, you want to make sure that the point (0,0) is always at the beginning of your data.

Here is a simple implementation, assuming that (0,0) is not already in your data:

```
function add_origin(group) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return [{key: 0, value: 0}].concat(group.all());
    }
  };
}
```

You can wrap your original group as you pass it into your chart:

```
lineChart
  .group(add_origin(group))
```

It might get more complicated if your data has any 0 or negative keys in it, but from your comments it sounds like your data is otherwise positive.

[image: line from origin]
[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/1vn8qu3p/10/)

Comment: I tried with this but now the lines are not drawing only it showing points. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I don't know what you mean without a running example. This should work. I'll post an example.

Comment: Generally you should include your code in every question you ask on SO, so that people can see what you are doing.

Comment: charts.push(dc.lineChart(compositeBrushchart).dimension(dim)
         .colors(config.charts[x].color).group((add_origin(grp)),config.charts[x].group)
           .interpolate(config.interpolate) .renderDataPoints(config.renderdatapoints)
            .renderArea(config.renderarea)
            .renderDataPoints({radius: config.charts[x].symbolsize})
            .dashStyle(config.charts[x].dash.split(","))
         .

Comment: Okay, I edited your question to add the code. I don't think this is enough to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you haven't given enough details for anyone to figure out what the problem is. I already posted a working example above, so clearly it does work, but I don't know, maybe you have different data or a different chart setup.

Comment: OK, in dc.js line chart ,when all y value is zero corresponding to the x axis value line is not drawing. it just displying xaxis and y-axis.Is it possible to draw line on the x axis with corresponding y value as 0 with x-axis name(field)?

Comment: Won’t you please edit your question and add a screenshot of the problem, and the code you use to initialize crossfilter?

Comment: Thanks for accepting - did this actually solve your problem though? :-)